Формат данных в pandas определяется некорректно
При загрузке данных в пандас - данные определяются не корректно. Все числа в исходном файле Excel - целые, без точек или запятых. Но при вводе функции df.info или describe, какие то данные выдаются с int64 а какие то с float64. Так же при вводе команды df.describe некоторые данные типа float64 считаются корректно вот так "210.000000", а типа int64 вот так: "2.100000e+02"
Не понимаю в чем проблема.


В ячейках Excel числа всегда только Double - с плавающей запятой двойной точности, 2)  Лучше разместить файл с примером, чтобы можно было разобраться, 3) Если вам нужен int64, сделайте приведение к нему astype()

